# what's the different between Socket.Connect and Socket.BeginConnect

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I meet a very strange problem: when I use Socket.Connect() in unity3d webplayer, meeting "System.Security.SecurityException: Unable to connect, as no valid crossdomain policy was found", but It's ok for Socket.BeginConnect(), so what's the difference?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/133806/why-is-unity-trying-to-get-a-crossdmain-policy-eve.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Socket.Connect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ych8bz3x.aspx

Socket.BeginConnect http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aeby4wt%28VS.80%29.aspx

As the documentation state Connect is synchronous that means it will block your current thread until the connection is made.

The BeginConnect method is asynchronous that means it will do the connection in a different thread and notify back when the connection is done. It will not block your current calling thread. You need to call EndConnect.

Socket.ConnectAsync provides SocketAsyncEventArgs as a parameters which contains a lot more information compared to 3 params provided by BeginConnect. Also I know that ConnectAsync introduced later than BeginConnect and solves some issues related to timeouts (cannot remember the source of this discussion now). Prefer ConnectAsync when possible (though it requires min .NET 2.0 SP1).

There is no support for BeginConnect method in Silverlight (only ConnectAsync is supported) so that may be another concern if you intend to develop client side Silverlight applications.